# Is the reported killing of Bengali people in East Pakistan accepted as genocide by the international community?

Tags: pakistan, genocide, bangladesh

Is the killing of Bengali people in [East Pakistan in 1971](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1971_Bangladesh_genocide) generally accepted as genocide by the international community?

If so:

1. Which organizations have officially recognized it as such (such as the United Nations Security Council, the United Nations General Assembly, the European Union, the United States, etc.)
2. Why has Pakistan never been taken to the International Criminal Court for crimes against humanity?

Comment: If you read the Wikipedia article on the [ICC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Criminal_Court) it has a lengthy section on jurisdiction which suggests the ICC (established in 2002) can't usually investigate something that happened in 1971. But this might be partly a matter of convention (or a reluctance to see litigation stretching back indefinitely), and a more substantive legal argument might be required to set out precise limits.